# How to save an array of images in a collection view swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

When I open my app, the first screen comes up with an empty `collectionView` of images. I press an 'add' button and it brings me to another `viewController`. This new screen has a `collectionView` with images inside of each `cell`. When i press on one of the images and press 'create' button. You are brought to the first screen again and see the image you have just selected in the first cell of the previously empty `collectionView`. I want to save that image in the `collectionView`, but I can't figure out how. I tried using `userDefault` but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Create and array in your 1st vc and then when you select any image then create delegate pattern and add that image/path into your 1st view controller's array. So every time you select any image, add it into your array. show that array into your collection view.

Comment: share your code which you tried so we could provide better solution.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani put it in answer.. 

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani I am showing the array that has the selected images from the other view controller. I just need to save them.

Comment: @nicholasdmoore It is up to you how long you want to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to save image into `NSMutableArray`. Using array you can manage your collectionview.

1. Create and array in your 1st View Controller.
2. Create Delegate into your 2nd View Controller.
3. Implement Delegate into 1st View Controller.
4. When you select Image/Path (Suggested Path), call your delegate and pass your data.
5. Now you are having that data into your delegate. Add that into your array.
6. Show that array into collectionview.

**Note**: This will add same image multiple times into array once you select. Manage your array accordingly your requirement.

Comment: I'm not really sure what "delegate' or 'NSMutableArray' is. Could you share some code so I could better understand what your'e saying?